# WSDL first call always take more then 10 seconds

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wsdl, httpurlconnection, service-reference

[VB.net]
Hi guys,

I have a small problem with my code.
There is an existing server abroad my home and i´m trying to create a connection to the Server and it works. 
My Problem is now, that the first call, also if its a login or a other method, it always takes about 10 seconds:[after first call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc1su.png)

Then when i call the first call, this happens:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuaZZ.png)

This is my AppConfig:

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="binding"></binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="link"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding"
                 contract="ServiceReference.serviceporttypüe" name="port" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IIS releases the resources after some time and when you make a call after that point, it takes a little longer to get a response from the service.

edit : check this also
[IIS-Auto-Start](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/)